# Something burnt out in my media PC, but not sure what

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

I have a simple compact media PC. Had it for a while and replaced the guts earlier this year (not the case or the PSU). I also moved it to a location that I now realize had much worse ventilation. It stopped working a few weeks back while giving off a distinct burnt smell. The power light would turn on when started, but no fans would turn on and no output to monitor/speakers. I assumed that the motherboard was cooked so I replaced it but it's still doing the exact thing. I used a multimeter to test the PSU output and it gave me all the correct voltages. What's confused me is that when I shorted out the pins to test it, the PSU fan turned on. It doesn't when it's plugged into the motherboard.

So what's broken?

Hardware info:

- Case : APEX MI-008 Black Steel Mini-ITX tower
- PSU:250W
- mobo: Gigabyte GA-H170N-WIFI

Comment: You make no mention of looking for or sniffing for the source of the *"burnt smell"*.   That's what you should have done first.

Comment: If there is just a case, a mobo and a power supply, and you have replaced the mobo and tested the power supply, then it sounds like a case issue. Except the case probably doesn't have components that'll fry and smell burnt. So you're probably back to one of the other two components being the issue. Except what about the CPU and Memory and HDD, and perhaps a graphics card? All these could be causing you trouble too. Have you tested each of them?